# Equality regarding power series and an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, integral-inequality, cauchy-integral-formula

Given the power series $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n(z-z_0)^n$ I have to prove that
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}|f(z_0+re^{it})|^2\;dt =\sum^\infty_{n=0}|c_n|^2r^{2n}$$
Here $ r>0$ is such that $\overline{B_r(z_0)}\subseteq U $ and $ U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is the region in which $ f$ is defined.
My idea is to prove that the LHS is less or equal than the RHS and vice versa. I already have prooved that 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}|f(z_0+re^{it})|^2\;dt \leq\sum^\infty_{n=0}|c_n|^2r^{2n}$$
Replacing $ |f(z_0+re^{it})|^2$ by the series and using the triangular inequality. I also know that 
$$c_nr^n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0+re^{it})e^{-int}\;dt $$

My next idea was to use Cauchy-Schwartz for the integral like this:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(z_0+re^{it})|^2\;dt= $$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(z_0+re^{it})|^2\;dt \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{int}|^2\;dt\right)}_{=1}  $$
$$ \geq \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-int}f(z_0+re^{it})\;dt\right|^2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}4\pi^2|c_n|^2r^{2n}=|c_n|^2r^{2n} $$

But this does not tell my anything about the series. I think I tried all the standard tools for inequalities with integrals and series and now I'm stuck on this.
It would be greate if any of you have any ideas or sugestions (not complete solutions, please).
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Hint: what is the explicit form of $|f(z_0+r\mathrm e^{\mathrm i t})|^2$?

Comment: Also $\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm e^{\mathrm i mt} \mathrm dt = ? [m \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}]$

Comment: I can't see where to use the explicit value of $|f(z_0+re^{it})|^2 $ other than this way:$ \int_0^{2\pi}| f(z_0+re^{it})|dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\sum c_n re^{it}\right|^2dt\geq \left|\int_0^{2\pi}\sum c_n re^{it}dt \right|^2$.

Comment: Write $f$ as the power series, and note that $|z|^2 = z \overline z$.

Comment: P.S. No need to use inequalities.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just realized it! There is no need of inequalities.